# Condition in Model Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i want `company_name` to be `unique=True` when `company_is_deleted=False`. Similarly when `company_is_deleted=True` then `company_name` to be `unique=False`. Where i am using soft delete means that i am just setting `company_is_deleted=True` and not deleting it from database table.

Company Model

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True) # Here
    company_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_email = models.EmailField()
    company_website = models.URLField()
    company_phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    company_monthly_payment = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    company_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='company_logo', default='default_company.png',blank=True, null=True)
    company_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    company_is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

View.py

```
class CompanyCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Company
    fields = ['company_name', 'company_description', 'company_email', 
    'company_website', 'company_address', 'company_phone', 'company_status', 
    'company_monthly_payment', 'company_logo']
```

Comment: Don't set `unique=True`. Instead, write a small `if...else` logic to get the behaviour that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add that logic into `save` method. But remove `unique` from `company_name` field.

```
from django.db import IntegrityError


class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    company_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_email = models.EmailField()
    company_website = models.URLField()
    company_phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    company_monthly_payment = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    company_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='company_logo', default='default_company.png',blank=True, null=True)
    company_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    company_is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.company_is_deleted and Company.objects.filter(
            company_name=self.company_name, 
            company_is_deleted=False
        ).exists():
            raise IntegrityError    
        super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: instead of raising Integrity Error i want to raise Validation Error. Similar to like this `raise forms.ValidationError(u'Email already exist.')`

Comment: You can override `save` method in your forms.py instead. So before hitting database, this condition is checked.

Comment: but i dont have forms.py i am using `generic.CreateView`